# WebGL interaction, translate after rotate

Tags: javascript, rotation, webgl, transformation, translate-animation

I'm having a little bit trouble with understanding rotation and translation stuff in context of a WebGL example.

**What's going on:** 
I have a sample program that lets me rotate a triangle around its center and translate it on a 2D plane. The code below does exactly that (uses the glmatrix libs). The modelViewMatrix is applied to the triangles vertices.

**The issue:** 
If the triangle is rotated by 180°, then the translation is wrong. Of course it is still possible to move the triangle around, but the directions are inverted. If I drag the triangle in an upward direction, the object actually moves further to the bottom of the screen.

**The question:** 
What is going on here and why is this happening? What do I need to do to correct this behaviour? I want to be able to drag the triangle no matter by how much it has been rotated, the tranlation axes should be consistent.

Thanks in advance for your replies, I'm sure it is an easy question for someone that is familiar with the whole transformation stuff. :)

```
var modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();

function mouseDown(mouseEvent){
    isMouseDown = true;
    g_drawInterval = setInterval(redraw, 40);
}

var translationFactor = 0.01;
var rotationFactor = 0.01;  

function mouseMove(mouseEvent){
    if (isMouseDown){
         deltaX = mouseEvent.clientX - oldPosX;
         deltaY = mouseEvent.clientY - oldPosY;
    if (mouseEvent.button === 0) // left mouse button
         mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix,
         [deltaX * translationFactor, -deltaY * translationFactor, 0]);
     else
         mat4.rotateZ(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix,
         deltaX * rotationFactor -deltaY * rotationFactor);
     }
     oldPosX = mouseEvent.clientX;
     oldPosY = mouseEvent.clientY;
 }
```

Comment: Here's an article on [how matrix math works](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html). Maybe it will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that your `modelViewMatrix` is *accumulating* the *compositions* of all the transformations.

The rotation functions typically rotate around the local origin (whatever that is, at the time it is applied). When you have some translate, you shift that origin around, so the rotate will behave differently.

I'm not sure about the "glmatrix" lib and about the shader's you use, but if both follow the default GL convention, you also have the effect that the transformations are applied in reverse order, so that

```
rotate(...);
translate(...)
```

will *first* translate and then rotate.

You can avoid this by keeping track of the orientation and the position separately, i.e. define a `position` vector and a `rotationMatrix` matrix, and update those accordingly. For drawing, you can combine them to the modelview matrix like

```
 modelViewMatrix=viewMatrix * translate(position) *  rotationMatrix
```

(Assuming the conventions descirbed above again).

Comment: Okay, by storing the current position in a separate vec3 I was able to solve the issue. Thanks.